# Add elements of array in jsonnet

Tags: jsonnet

I am trying to add elements of an array in jsonnet. Can someone post a sample?

Sample
input: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

output
`6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [std.foldl()](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html#foldl) as the "aggregation" function:

```
local myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];

std.foldl(function(x, y) (x + y), myArray, 0)
```

Comment: For completeness: you can also write your own recursive function which is the most general way to accumulate stuff:
`local sum(arr) = local aux(arr, index, acc) = if index < std.length(arr) then aux(arr, index + 1, acc + arr[index]) else acc; aux(arr, 0, 0); sum([1, 2, 3])`
Using foldl is the recommended way.